# Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event' for Angular2 NavigationEnd Event

Tags: angularjs, angular, routes, router, angular-routing

```
    this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
        console.log(event.url); ##### Error : Property 'url' does not exist on type 'Event'.
   }
```

Typescript doesn't recognize the properties of the type Event that is built into the Angular Router. Is there something on tsd that I can use to solve this? Event is the super class of classes NaviagationEnd, NavigationStart

Comment: Have you imported events form @angular/router.   Try moving console in if block with condition if(event instanceof NavigationEnd )

Comment: you got it! thanks, Im new to this typescript thing

Comment: Updated this as answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You have to `import { Event } from @angular/router;`. Try moving console into the `if` block with condition.

```
this.subscription = this.router.events.subscribe((event:Event) => {
  if(event instanceof NavigationEnd ){
    console.log(event.url);
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you, that's what I was looking for in order to filter specific events.

Comment: Don't think you need to import Event and define it explicitly; the `event instanceof NavigationEnd` bit should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Router event are usually used to watch router states and can write custom logic as requirement.

we can use NavigationStart or NavigationEnd to achieve states.

step 1: add import statement

```
import { Router, NavigationStart, Event as NavigationEvent } from '@angular/router';
```

`
step 2: add below code.

```
this.router.events
  .subscribe(
    (event: NavigationEvent) => {
      if(event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        console.log(event.url);
      }
    });
```