# Property "url" does not exit on type never?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a need to subscribe for router events: `NavigationStart` and `NavigationEnd`

```
this._router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .subscribe((event: NavigationStart | NavigationEnd) => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
               // event.url, typescript does not flag any error
            }
            else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
               // typescript flags, that property "url" does not exist on type "never".
               // if I make this block as the only block,
               // i.e. remove the previous "if" block and put this under "if"
               // then it works fine
            }
            // event.url, works fine, even here
        });
```

Why is typescript not recognizing `event` as a type of `NavigationStart` or `NavigationEnd`? Although when I console "event" inside "else if", I get all the properties of "event".

I have seen [this link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38398424/property-url-does-not-exist-on-type-event-for-angular2-navigationend-event) (didn't work for me) and [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10422), people have given various reasons for closing this issue, `design limitations`. Is there a workaround for what I want to  achieve, `other than doing:`

```
.subscribe((event: any) => {})
```

> **EDIT :** Implementation of @Saravana's solution

[image]

Comment: have you tried renaming event to something else?

Comment: Yes, tried that! take a different name in `subscribe` to what I use in `filter`. That doesn't work. What works is, I make an alias of `event` like : `let alias = event` before `if block`. Use, `event` in `if condition` and `alias` in `else if condition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an open issue with the TypeScript compiler. See https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11664

Possible workaround in your case you can flip the condition to check for `NavigationEnd` first. Since `NavigationEnd` contains all properties of `NavigationStart`, the compiler thinks that all instances of `NavigationEnd` are `NavigationStart` instances:

```
this._router.events
  .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd)
  .subscribe((event: NavigationStart | NavigationEnd) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {

        }
        else if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {

        }
});
```

Comment: Well I guess, `any` has got to come somewhere, even the `angular` people will do something similar. Thanks, it works :)

Comment: And BTW, I guess, typescript doesn't let write the "function" keyword before functions.

Comment: You can use the `function` keyword before functions. If you are defining it inside a class the syntax is a little different.

Comment: And you don't even have to use `any` in the type guard. See my updated answer.

Comment: @sarvana, I did some mistake while implementing your solution, I had not replaced `.subscribe((event: any))` with the `Navigation` types, but now when I have replaced them, it shows the same error, `property url does not exist on type never`

Comment: Did you use the type guard function? Post what you have done.

Comment: My bad. I was having the conditions flipped when I tried. See my updated answer. It is not a great solution. I guess you will have to wait till the issue is fixed with the TypeScript compiler if you want to do it correctly.

Comment: Oh!! Its a nice work around. It works, confirmed! Thanks :)